# How to convert PST timezone date to Local TimeZone in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc, pst

I'm getting the date in `PST TimeZone` and need to convert it to `local TimeZone`. I'm developing a product in CRM so TimeZone can be changed user to user.

I tried to use `moment JS` but for that, we need to specify the country/ city name and all I'm getting is `TimeZoneOffset`. I have a code for `UTC` to local time zone if it gets converted to `UTC` also then my work will be done.

`Fri Jan 17 2020 22:57:49 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`
Need the answer in `TS` if possible or `JS` will be ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Convert other time zones to local time zone. You can use the following in javascript.

```
var date = new Date(other time zone value);
date.toString();
```

For example

```
var date = new Date('Fri Jan 17 2020 22:57:49 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)');
date.toString();
```

result will be "Sat Jan 18 2020 12:27:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"